# Are we entitled to flight compensation?

Tags: air-travel, compensation, missed-flights, vueling

We arrived at Marseilles airport ready to check in and bag drop on our way to Rome. The women at the information desk for Vueling said there was no flight today and it was changed to yesterday, we had received an email with the change but missed the date change.

Can we get any compensation?

I know it was our fault for not looking at the date but still a 24 hour change is taking the piss.

Comment: That's a bummer.  How much notice did you get with the date change?

Comment: Unless the mail contained, in the subject line and in all caps, "attention, date changed", I don't think you should let them tell you that it is your fault.

Comment: I think only an email is not very much, even when it holds all warnings. When traveling you often are not in a position to check your e-mails.

Comment: @Willeke considering email is a *primary* method of contact these days - how else do you expect them to contact you?  Letter is even worse, especially if you are travelling (even less of a position to check your mail than your email).  Airline to phone each and every passenger on the aircraft?

Comment: @Moo By not allowing a flight to be done earlier than planned, not by more than about 2 hours. If a flight needs to be moved, it should be later, not earlier. Or at least, if it is earlier, the company should allow people who not have reacted on the mail to use a later flight instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, assuming you were not informed more than two weeks prior the flight. From [Air Passenger Rights](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm):

> Cancellation or denied boarding
>
> If your flight is cancelled, **and you were informed less than 2 weeks
>   prior to the scheduled date** or you're denied boarding you're entitled
>   to:
>
> - Transport to your final destination using comparable alternative transport means; or
>
>   - A refund for your ticket; or
>   - Transport free of charge to your initial departure point if you have connecting flights; and
> - Financial compensation of EUR 250 to EUR 600 depending on the distance of your flight. If the carrier offers you an alternative
>     flight, and you reach your final destination with a delay of 2, 3 or 4
>     hours depending on the length of the flight, the compensation may be
>     reduced by 50% (see below).
>
> In cases of re-routing, you are also entitled to care (drinks, meals,
>   communications) and, if necessary, hotel accommodation (including
>   transfer) depending on the length of the delay.

Please note that compensation is due anyway, even if the airline provides alternative transportation or refunds your ticket. The airline also is required to provide accommodations (see the last sentence). As usual, you'll likely have to raise your voice and probably post a written complain to get anything from an airline.

Comment: I don't see how this matters. "You were informed" not by the moment an e-mail was sent (it could technically stuck for a week in transit), but at the moment you received this information. Until you received it, you're not informed.

Comment: Good point. I've updated the answer. Although it would be interesting to see how the airline would prove in court that they indeed informed you.